# Multiple stacks with a persistent navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to build an app using flutter that has a bottom navigation bar that remains in view through sub pages. Any help?

I'm very new to flutter and coding in general. I've been able to get a working material navigation bar that highlights the current page but when I push to another route on that page, the bar disappears. This convention would work for some areas of my app, but a few pages are 3 "layers" deep and I would like to keep the bar so the user maintains a sense of place.

From what I've researched, Cupertino's navigation bar allows for this but I would prefer accomplishing this with material bottom navigation and routing.

Here's a general look at what I'm trying to accomplish (minus login/splashpage/onboard/etc.)

[Prototype showing the routing of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6byz.png)

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Check if this tutorial work for you. https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation

Comment: I toyed with this, but couldn't get it figured out right away. I think you need Nested Navigators. (It's toward the bottom): https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html